# How to save read only ppt to pdf?

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-4.0, office-interop

when i tried to save a read- only ppt/pptx to a pdf i got a msg as shown below

[image]

below is my code:

```
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application pptApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application();
        pptApplication.DisplayAlerts = PpAlertLevel.ppAlertsNone;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation pptPresentation = pptApplication.Presentations.Open("E:\\Share Box\\data.pptx", MsoTriState.msoTriStateMixed,
        MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoFalse);

        string temp = pptPresentation.ReadOnly.ToString();

        pptPresentation.SaveAs("E:\\Share Box\\"+DateTime.Now.Second.ToString(), PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsPDF, MsoTriState.msoTrue);

        pptPresentation.Close();

        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(pptPresentation);
        pptPresentation = null;
        pptApplication.Quit();

        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(pptApplication);
        pptApplication = null;

        GC.Collect();
```

anyone could help me to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code and it's working fine.For this I used interop assemblies downloaded from 
http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=3508

Please see this also

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/873433